# Is longest common subsequence with bounded occurrences NP-complete?

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, np-hardness

The general [longest common subsequence problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_subsequence_problem) (LCS) over a binary alphabet is NP-complete. Does the problem remain NP-complete if each input string has *m* zeros and *n* ones, where *m* and *n* are constants?

I asked this question on [cs.stackexchange](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/44306/computational-complexity-of-longest-common-subsequence-problem-variation) and was told, "The problem probably remains NP-complete." However, I was unsuccessful in showing a reduction from the original LCS problem.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This [paper by Blin et al.](http://pagesperso.lina.univ-nantes.fr/~bulteau-l/pdf/BBJTV-cpm12.pdf) (Hardness of Longest Common Subsequence for Sequences with Bounded Run-Lengths, CPM'12) provides a reduction from independent set to LCS where the Hamming weights of all strings are the same (it is $n-1$ where $n$ is the number of vertices in the independent set instance). Thus, the problem remains NP-complete under this assumption.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. In this case the Hamming Weight (no. of 1's) are fixed to a constant M in each string. Assuming, both the number of 1's and 0's are fixed (i.e. the string sizes are same along with the Hamming Weight) does the LCS problem reduce to P ?

Comment: In the reduction by Blin et al., all of the strings have the same number of 0's and 1's.

Answer (score -3):

I believe the problem was shown to be NP-Hard, as opposed to NP-Complete.  I am not personally familiar with any proof of reducibility of SAT to LCS.  Such a proof is required for a problem to be regarded as NP-Complete.  NP-Complete essentially means that a given problem is at least as hard as SAT.  The reduction of a problem to SAT in P-time and P-space merely shows the problem is itself no harder the SAT.  The LCS problem has a P-time and P-space solution as an answer set problem.

Comment: please provide some links to support these claims

Comment: To the 4 down voters: How dare you! This answer is excellent. User36160 says (very original name btw) "[got links]?" - use Google is my reply.

Comment: It’s important to note that the LCSq between 2 strings is NP-Hard, when comparing 3 strings the problem is NP-Complete according to Wikipedia’s list of NP-Complete problems.